# Multithreading in c++ ending unexpectledly

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm a newbie in multithread, so the problem is: I'm trying to make multiple threads send message to a server, ever thread represents a device. The server who I'm testing has 10k ports open so every socket has his exclusively port. The problem is the program subtly stops and don't send all messages from all devices. I'm using a vector of futures to simulate the devices, that way:

```
vector<future<void>> futures;
map<string,vector<string> >::iterator it = mapDevtoMessage.begin();
for(it = mapDevtoMessage.begin(); it != mapDevtoMessage.end(); it++){
  futures.push_back(async(launch::async,[&]{ send_messages(it->second, it->first);}));
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
}
for(auto &its : futures){
  its.wait();
}
```

The code for send_messages is:

```
void send_messages (vector<string>& vec, string name){
  mtx.lock();
  PORT++;
  mtx.unlock();
  int sock = 0, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
       printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
    }
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0) {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
    }
  if ((client_fd
        = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,
                  sizeof(serv_addr)))
      < 0) {
      printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
  }
  for(auto &i : vec){
    string val = hexToASCII(i);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    send(sock, val.c_str(), 100, 0);
    mtx.lock();
    printf("\nmessage %s from %s send\n", i.c_str() , name.c_str());
    mtx.unlock();
  }

    // closing the connected socket
  close(client_fd);
}
```

I added the for loop with the wait() method because the program keep terminating unexpectledly without any error or anything. So I added, but the program continues to subtle terminate. I tried an endless loop also. I may have missed a simple thing (I'm a noob), please let me know.

Comment: without going further into it. its good practice to wrap critical statements in try/catch blocks and printing out the received error ^^ i will take a closer look into your code now

Comment: Try changing the lambda capture in your `async` call from `&` to `=`.  I suspect that the reference is causing you issues as what `it` points to can change while `async` is spinning up the thread.  Basically the use of `it` and the `it++` operation have no sequencing guarantee between them.

Comment: I'd guess if you debug then you'd find some of your `async` calls are dereferencing the `end` iterator

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve]. It happens that it becomes so simple that the reason for the unexpected ending becomes obvious, which is also why it's actually required for a Q here. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].